# Type "LocationComponent" is part of the declarations of 2 modules:Angular 6?

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, angular6

I am completely new to angular, so I cant able to resolve my error using other stack flow answers. Kindly help.

I am using an angular 6. I already have a basic format,so I am trying to add child page. But I got this error **'Type LocationComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules'** and stuck in this for about 2 days.

Here is the picture of format of My src folder: [image: My src folder:]

My app.module.ts codings as follows:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CommonModule, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule, NgModuleFactory } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LocationComponent } from './masterpage/location/location.component';
import { StorageComponent } from './masterpage/storage/storage.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SpinnerComponent,         
    LocationComponent,
    StorageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,   
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),      
    AppRoutingModule,        
  ],
  providers: [
      {
      provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
      useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
    },{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app-routing.module.ts as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: FullComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/masterpage/location', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'masterpage', loadChildren: './masterpage/masterpage.module#MasterPageModule' }, 
    ]
}];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), NgbModule.forRoot()],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My masterpage.module.ts codes as follows:

```
import { NgModule,Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationComponent } from './location/location.component';
import { StorageComponent } from './storage/storage.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MasterPageRoutes } from './masterpage.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        CommonModule,
        NgbModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(MasterPageRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        LocationComponent,
        StorageComponent,
    ]
})
export class MasterPageModule { }
```

My masterpage.routing.ts codes are below:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationComponent } from './location/location.component';
import { StorageComponent } from './storage/storage.component';

export const MasterPageRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
    {
      path: 'location',
      component: LocationComponent,
      data: {
        title: 'Location',
        urls: [{title: 'Location',url: '/location'},{title: 'Location'}]
      }
    }, {
      path: 'storage',
      component: StorageComponent,
      data: {
        title: 'Storage',
        urls: [{title: 'Storage',url: '/storage'},{title: 'Storage'}]
      }
    }
]
  }
];
```

My Sample previously running with the url **'/localhost:4200/#/dashboard/dashboard1'**-this was the sample. I changed the dashboard as per my request as 'masterpage' and its children 'dashboard1' and 'dashboard2' to 'location' and 'storage' respectively. I want the children pages location and storage must load with the url **'/localhost:4200/#/masterpage/location'**
 But its not working for me. No error in code page. Error I found out in console under inspect elements only.

Kindly help me what is wrong in it.. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already declared **LocationComponent** in app.module.ts, it is already available app wide. So, there is no need to declare it again in **masterpage.module.ts**.

Remove **LocationComponent** in **masterpage.module.ts** from declarations array and also get rid of the imports.

Comment: Thank you so much, but ur answer worked for me in reverse side. When I remove it from the masterpage.module.ts, its still not working, as it is a child page I removed from app.module.ts page components and added it back in module page. Its working.. Thank you so much to you. Kindly update ur answer and I will mark it as crct one....

Comment: The reason is: Masterpage is a module containing LocationComponent and StorageComponent. And you want to access these component **EXCLUSIVELY** to your MasterPage module, as they wont be available outside of the MasterPageModule scope. So, it's ok to remove from appmodule. I've a query, where did you register your masterPageModule in the app?

Comment: In my app.routing.ts page on the link I give the MasterpageModule access